# Pasar un type de typescript como validacion a zod

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy intentando resolver un problema que creo que es muy comun pero la verdad no encuentro la solucion.

Yo normalmente uso use-form-query en react para llenar formularios y empecé a usar zod para la validación de los mismos. Pero me pasa que quiero validar con zod algunos types de typescript cuales no controlo, que vienen de otras librerías y no puedo.

No puedo hacer algo como esto:

```
import { FileWithPath } from "react-dropzone";

export const validationSchema = z.object({
  attachments: FileWithPath []; <- no puedo hacer esto
});

Existe una solucion a esto?

Gracias.
```